# System with serial console, which system is responsible for flow control settings

Tags: linux, boot, init, serial-console, protocols

I have a proprietary Linux system, with a proprietary init system, which uses a serial console. I lately noticed, that the xon/xoff flow control is active on this serial console, which poses the risk of hanging the boot process when the xon character (0x13) is received by line noise. Looking at other systems with serial consoles (systemd based) shows that flow control is disabled there for the serial console, which seems sane.

The question is, which part of the system is responsible for deactivating the flow control of the console tty? Is this done by the init process or the kernel itself? I.e., is this an error within the kernel configuration or must the init system be fixed to disable the flow control?

I know, that the flow control can be disabled using the `tcsetattr()` function or by running `stty -ixon -F /dev/console`, but for a reliable system, this should be disabled before any process writes output to the console. I already browsed the systemd source code but wasn't able to find any code disabling flow control there.

Comment: Proprietary init system… you don't tell much. systemd-like ? openrc-like ? What sort of process is responsible for opening the port, getty ? agetty ?

Comment: A custom build init system, not comparable to systemd, systemv-init, openrc or even simple init. It's there, I didn't choose it :/ Busybox is used to provide the login prompt, but that shouldn't be that relevant since the problem of possible stopping console output arises long before login or a getty gets active. If the init process prints output to the console and the flow control is stopped using the xon signal (^S), boot stops before any of this get active.

I can see just two instances, which could be the right place to disable the flow control, init or the kernel. Which is used normaly?

Comment: OK I see. You write :  "the xon character (0x13) is received by line noise". Are you sure about that ? (I mean compared to what line noise would more likely throw that is hardware RTS/CTS controls ?) In addition what is your terminal ? Is there whatever local (OS independent) setup available ?

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledging that I know nothing of your proprietary Linux system and not more about your proprietary init system :

> I lately noticed, that the xon/xoff flow control is active on this
> serial console, which poses the risk of hanging the boot process when
> the xon character (0x13) is received by line noise

As far as the boot phase (prior to init) is concerned this just cannot happen for any stock Linux. Simply because, whatever its configuration, the kernel does not handle software flow control at boot time.
At boot time, the kernel can handle hardware flow control (RTS/CTS) but only if especially instructed to do so via the [`console` boot command line parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) since it won't per default.

Your bootlog should tell you whether the boot command line includes special settings for the console or not. And if the setting includes a final **r** (see herabove link) and your line is noisy enough to generate spurious RTS/CTS… then remove the **r** from the setting.

Whatever init will happily go on with these settings until… it leaves to some `getty` (or like : agetty, mgetty…) process the responsibility to open the port and set the desired line discipline.

Under whatever standard linux distribution, this process would be [agetty](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/agetty.8.html) which will default to ignoring hardware flow control and, contrarily to other similar processes will activate the software flow control (XON/XOFF) leaving to whatever following process the responsibility to disable it if found inappropriate.

Therefore you should first get the knowledge of which process is handling the ttys you did not log on. Simply fire some `ps -ax` command and look for lines of the kind (as now on my system) :

```
1515 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty 38400 tty2 linux
```

If, as reported above `agetty` is running then, as justified above, you will necessarily have to resort to the `stty` command you know well (since the /usr/bin/login process launched after `agetty` cannot change anything of the line discipline).
If the process is different then just report, there might be options for disabling software control flow.

---

Of course, for having myself worked with serial lines in noisy environments… this is just nightmare as part of which… spurious XOFFs take a very little part.
If your line is that noisy then reduce the baudrate.
Installing RS232/RS485 convertors saved my hairs… ;-)